# How would I get an image to appear at specific coordinates in iOS based on user input?

Tags: ios, image, coordinates

In Xcode, how would I make an image appear in a certain place on the iPhone screen by touching the place where I would want it to appear? The method that I'm currently trying to use is by getting the coordinates of the point and then trying to get a png file to appear at that point. Here is what I have so far for code:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches
            withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [theTouch locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat x = startPoint.x;
    CGFloat y = startPoint.y;
```

But now that I have the points, I'm not sure how to get an image to appear there or if there might be a more efficient method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`[-UIImage drawAtPoint:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

After getting x,y coordinates of a touch event, set center point of your UIImageView to it.

```
UIImageView *myImage = ...

CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(x_touch, y_touch);

[myImage setCenter:myPoint];
```

you can also animate this change by using animate block on the image view like so:

```
    nsTimerInterval myAnimationDuration = 1.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:myAnimationDuration animations:^{
        [myImage setCenter:myPoint];

    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        //handle completion tasks

    }];
```